# Android (root) - Force image for camera

Tags: android, camera, root, barcode-scanner, xposed

I was wondering if there are any apps/(Xposed) modules which can force an image to be seen by the camera.

Basically, I'd like a scanner to scan a self-made barcode rather than needing two phones; one to generate and show the barcode and the other to scan it from a specific app.

Anything that will show an image for the scanner in an app will do.

Comment: Have you found an answer?